# RODBC query not returning data

Tags: sql, oracle, r

I am completely stumped as to why I am not able to return valid data when writing a query against an Oracle data warehouse.

I have previously seen the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956138/rodbc-returning-0-values), as well as this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425100/rodbc-queries-returning-zero-rows), but neither fixed my problem.

Some background:

- I connect to the Oracle data warehouse every day and usually do not have any problems with pulling data into R
- When I list the tables in the schema, the Table_Type is listed as "TABLE"
- I can use SPSS to query the table in the database without issue.  I am doing everything in my power to remove SPSS from my workflow.

My code which attempts to use the solutions found above:

```
ch <- odbcConnect(DSN, USER, PWD)
tmp <- sqlQuery(ch, "SELECT * from MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM", rows_at_time=1)
```

This is what is returned (incorrect column names start at column 9):

```
> tmp
 [1] COMM_ITEM_PK            COMM_ERROR_PK           COMM_ADDRESS_PRLO_PK   
 [4] COMM_ADDRESS_LOPR_PK    COMM_ADDRESS_PR_PK      COMM_OUTBOUNDMESSAGE_ID
 [7] COMM_PIDM               COMM_CREATED_BY         ?                      
[10] ?.1                     ?.2                     ?.3                    
[13] ?.4                     ?.5                     ?.6                    
[16] ?.7                     ?.8                     ?.9                    
[19] ?.10                    ?.11                    ?.12                   
[22] ?.13                    ?.14                    ?.15                   
[25] ?.16                    ?.17                    ?.18                   
[28] ?.19                    ?.20                    ?.21                   
[31] ?.22                    ?.23                    ?.24                   
[34] ?.25                    ?.26                    ?.27                   
[37] ?.28                    ?.29                    ?.30                   
[40] ?.31                    ?.32                    ?.33                   
[43] ?.34                    ?.35                   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Here is my connection info:

```
> odbcGetInfo(ch)
       DBMS_Name         DBMS_Ver  Driver_ODBC_Ver Data_Source_Name      Driver_Name 
        "Oracle"     "11.01.0070"          "03.51"           "MYDSN"    "SQORA32.DLL" 
      Driver_Ver         ODBC_Ver      Server_Name 
    "09.02.0000"     "03.80.0000"       "myserver "
```

Lastly, my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RODBC_1.3-5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.0
```

I would really like to stay with the RODBC package.  I know there are quite a few complaints, but basically, all I need is to pull data down with the occasional upload back to the database.

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE:  Here is some info about the table:

```
> sqlColumns(ch, "MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM")[3:7]
                TABLE_NAME                COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE        TYPE_NAME COLUMN_SIZE
1  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_ITEM_PK         3          DECIMAL          19
2  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              COMM_ERROR_PK         3          DECIMAL          19
3  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM       COMM_ADDRESS_PRLO_PK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
4  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM       COMM_ADDRESS_LOPR_PK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
5  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_ADDRESS_PR_PK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
6  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM    COMM_OUTBOUNDMESSAGE_ID        12         VARCHAR2         144
7  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                  COMM_PIDM         3          DECIMAL          19
8  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_CREATED_BY        12         VARCHAR2        1020
9  MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_CREATION_DATE        -4     TIMESTAMP(3)  2147483647
10 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM COMM_GENERIC_TEMPLATE_NAME        12         VARCHAR2        1020
11 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_TEMPLATE_NAME        12         VARCHAR2        2044
12 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM      COMM_TEMPLATE_VERSION        12         VARCHAR2        1020
13 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             DATE_COMM_SENT        -4     TIMESTAMP(3)  2147483647
14 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             COMM_DATE_SENT        -4     TIMESTAMP(3)  2147483647
15 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM COMM_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL        12         VARCHAR2        1020
16 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_SUBJECT        12         VARCHAR2        1020
17 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              COMM_EMAIL_PK         3          DECIMAL          19
18 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_TO_ADDRESS        12         VARCHAR2        1020
19 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_ISP_DOMAIN        12         VARCHAR2        4000
20 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                COMM_CCLIST        12         VARCHAR2        1020
21 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_BCCLIST        12         VARCHAR2        1020
22 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_REPLYTO        12         VARCHAR2        1020
23 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                COMM_SENDER        12         VARCHAR2        1020
24 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_REFERENCE_DESC        12         VARCHAR2        1020
25 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM          COMM_OPTOUT_TOKEN        12         VARCHAR2        1020
26 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_DELIVERED_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
27 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM           COMM_OPTOUT_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
28 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM           COMM_OPTOUT_DATE        93             DATE          19
29 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_OPTOUT_CHANNEL        12         VARCHAR2         200
30 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_OPTIN_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
31 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_OPTIN_DATE        93             DATE          19
32 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_OPTIN_CHANNEL        12         VARCHAR2         200
33 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_OPTLOCK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
34 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_ERROR_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
35 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM          COMM_BOUNCED_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
36 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_ONE_OFF         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
37 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_OWNERID        12         VARCHAR2        1020
38 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             COMM_OWNERNAME        12         VARCHAR2        2044
39 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             COMM_OWNER_KEY         3          DECIMAL          19
40 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                COMM_ORG_ID         3          DECIMAL          19
41 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              COMM_ORG_NAME        12         VARCHAR2        1020
42 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_CONTENT_PURGED        12         VARCHAR2          16
43 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_ACTIVITY_DATE        93             DATE          19
44 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              ACTIVITY_DATE        93             DATE          19
45 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_ITEM_PK         3          DECIMAL          19
46 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              COMM_ERROR_PK         3          DECIMAL          19
47 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM       COMM_ADDRESS_PRLO_PK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
48 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM       COMM_ADDRESS_LOPR_PK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
49 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_ADDRESS_PR_PK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
50 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM    COMM_OUTBOUNDMESSAGE_ID        12         VARCHAR2         144
51 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                  COMM_PIDM         3          DECIMAL          19
52 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_CREATED_BY        12         VARCHAR2        1020
53 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_CREATION_DATE        -4     TIMESTAMP(3)  2147483647
54 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM COMM_GENERIC_TEMPLATE_NAME        12         VARCHAR2        1020
55 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_TEMPLATE_NAME        12         VARCHAR2        2044
56 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM      COMM_TEMPLATE_VERSION        12         VARCHAR2        1020
57 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             DATE_COMM_SENT        -4     TIMESTAMP(3)  2147483647
58 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             COMM_DATE_SENT        -4     TIMESTAMP(3)  2147483647
59 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM COMM_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL        12         VARCHAR2        1020
60 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_SUBJECT        12         VARCHAR2        1020
61 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              COMM_EMAIL_PK         3          DECIMAL          19
62 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_TO_ADDRESS        12         VARCHAR2        1020
63 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_ISP_DOMAIN        12         VARCHAR2        4000
64 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                COMM_CCLIST        12         VARCHAR2        1020
65 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_BCCLIST        12         VARCHAR2        1020
66 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_REPLYTO        12         VARCHAR2        1020
67 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                COMM_SENDER        12         VARCHAR2        1020
68 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_REFERENCE_DESC        12         VARCHAR2        1020
69 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM          COMM_OPTOUT_TOKEN        12         VARCHAR2        1020
70 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_DELIVERED_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
71 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM           COMM_OPTOUT_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
72 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM           COMM_OPTOUT_DATE        93             DATE          19
73 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_OPTOUT_CHANNEL        12         VARCHAR2         200
74 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_OPTIN_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
75 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_OPTIN_DATE        93             DATE          19
76 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_OPTIN_CHANNEL        12         VARCHAR2         200
77 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_OPTLOCK         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
78 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM            COMM_ERROR_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
79 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM          COMM_BOUNCED_FLAG         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
80 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_ONE_OFF         8 DOUBLE PRECISION           0
81 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM               COMM_OWNERID        12         VARCHAR2        1020
82 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             COMM_OWNERNAME        12         VARCHAR2        2044
83 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM             COMM_OWNER_KEY         3          DECIMAL          19
84 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM                COMM_ORG_ID         3          DECIMAL          19
85 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              COMM_ORG_NAME        12         VARCHAR2        1020
86 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM        COMM_CONTENT_PURGED        12         VARCHAR2          16
87 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM         COMM_ACTIVITY_DATE        93             DATE          19
88 MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM              ACTIVITY_DATE        93             DATE          19
```

Comment: There were suggestions in the past to set `believeNRows=FALSE` when you call `odbcConnect()` (which calls `odbcDriverConnect()`). Did you try that?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the DDL for the table involved.  Thanks.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Yes, I tried that as well. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: So It looks like the issue is that the ODBC connection freaks out over the timestamp format.

Comment: It seems that all the fields names are duplicated.  For example, COMM_ITEM_PK is field #1, and also field #45.  Are there 44 or 88 fields in this table?

Comment: Can you try connecting to the database using something besides ODBC?

Comment: Can anyone here take a look at this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127433/rodbc-query-falsely-returning-zero-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my thinking, and something to try.

It's interesting to me that the field it fails on is the first instance of a TIMESTAMP in the table.  Working on the theory that TIMESTAMP may have something to do with it, first let's create a view on MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM that casts all the TIMESTAMP fields to DATE:

```
CREATE VIEW MV_BRM_COMM_DM_VIEW AS
  SELECT COMM_ITEM_PK, COMM_ERROR_PK, COMM_ADDRESS_PRLO_PK,
         COMM_ADDRESS_LOPR_PK, COMM_ADDRESS_PR_PK,
         COMM_OUTBOUNDMESSAGE_ID, COMM_PIDM, COMM_CREATED_BY,
         TO_DATE(COMM_CREATION_DATE) AS COMM_CREATION_DATE,
         COMM_GENERIC_TEMPLATE_NAME, COMM_TEMPLATE_NAME,
         COMM_TEMPLATE_VERSION,
         TO_DATE(DATE_COMM_SENT) AS DATE_COMM_SENT,
         TO_DATE(COMM_DATE_SENT) AS COMM_DATE_SENT,
         COMM_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL, COMM_SUBJECT, COMM_EMAIL_PK,
         COMM_TO_ADDRESS, COMM_ISP_DOMAIN, COMM_CCLIST,
         COMM_BCCLIST, COMM_REPLYTO, COMM_SENDER, COMM_REFERENCE_DESC,
         COMM_OPTOUT_TOKEN, COMM_DELIVERED_FLAG, COMM_OPTOUT_FLAG,
         COMM_OPTOUT_DATE, COMM_OPTOUT_CHANNEL, COMM_OPTIN_FLAG,
         COMM_OPTIN_DATE, COMM_OPTIN_CHANNEL, COMM_OPTLOCK,
         COMM_ERROR_FLAG, COMM_BOUNCED_FLAG, COMM_ONE_OFF,
         COMM_OWNERID, COMM_OWNERNAME, COMM_OWNER_KEY, COMM_ORG_ID,
         COMM_ORG_NAME, COMM_CONTENT_PURGED, COMM_ACTIVITY_DATE,
         ACTIVITY_DATE
    FROM MV_BRM_COMMUNICATION_DM
```

Now, change your SELECT to read from the view, and see if things work differently.

Not guaranteed as I can't test against your environment, but it's something to start from.

Share and enjoy.