# output format of Sys.Date()

Tags: r

The function `Sys.Date()` returns a date object, but on different machines running R2.12 I get different outputs

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "08/17/2011 00:00:00.000 UTC"
```

vs.

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2011-08-17"
```

The former looks like a POSIX object, even though it's still a date object. What possible differences in settings between the two environments may cause this problem?

Comment: I'm almost certain this is related to whatever was causing your issues in [Different dates formats in zoo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5915728/271616).

Comment: The first is oddly formatted - the ordering of the date part is wrong and there are `/` - so I doubt it *is* a POSIX class. `Sys.Date()` shouldn't be returning anything like the first. What are the OSes of the two machines? `Sys.Date()` is implemented as `as.Date(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))` could you post a break down of those steps - output from `Sys.time()`, output from `as.POSIXlt()` on that time etc.

Comment: I recall seeing a similar problem on a misconfigured system.  In addition to the output Gavin requested, can you also output `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the systems are set to different locales?  Try

```
Sys.getlocale();
```

Another possible scenario is that some nefarious soul "overwrote" the `Sys.Date()` function with another.  Try running

```
base::Sys.Date();
```

on both systems.  If you have a package, other than base, that is loading a function called `Sys.Date()` then you should call `base::Sys.Date()` to be sure you get the right one.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Was one of your boxes OS X?